# div gets cut off for chrome with a smaller screen

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have a very simple HTML page with the following body:

```
<body>
    <div class="home">
        <img src="finalized3.png" usemap="#nav" hidefocus="true" />
        <map name="nav">
            <area shape="poly" coords="190,279,220,277,248,266,276,263,287,271,284,275,293,275,300,290,299,303,311,326,297,334,300,346,287,360,233,368,206,384,171,378,133,393,109,394,107,382,97,379,94,357,82,335,95,324,104,303,164,291" href="MENU.pdf"/>
            <area shape="poly" coords="642,271,702,291,724,291,741,300,799,316,809,328,807,336,817,346,804,369,805,391,790,394,778,405,763,407,705,384,687,386,668,375,603,357,597,339,588,331,600,311,603,283,621,282,627,273" href="eng-location.html"/>
            <area shape="rect" coords="331,563,814,597" href="mailto:restaurantharuhana@gmail.com"/>
        </map> 
    </div>
</body>
```

with the following CSS code:

```
body {
background-image: url(background.jpg);
}

.home {
    width: 910px;
    height: 740px;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}

img[usemap], map area{
    outline: none;
}
```

This looks perfectly fine on Firefox, but on Chrome, on a smaller screen, the div gets cut off at the top. I want the div image to be in the center of the page and not be cut off no matter the size of the screen. How can I fix this? Thank you.

Comment: why don't you give width and height in terms of percentage?

Comment: If you want to display as it as try min-width home class.

Comment: If I give width and height in terms of percentage, it's not centered anymore, even though it does solve the problem of div getting cut off..